# "managed_file" form field type returns null value in my form submission

Tags: 8, forms

I am have been struggling with this for the past day or so. I am simply trying to create a custom entity and populate/or update the image field with the fid. Whats weird is that every other form field I am passing I can get the value for but this managed_file field for uploading an image always returns NULL when I call `dpm()`.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
```

Within my form_build function, I use the following code.

```
// Manage file.
$form['theimage'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => 'Managed file',
  '#description' => $this->t('Manage file, #type = managed_file'),
  //'#default_value' => $form_state->getValue('theimage'),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://images/',
  '#required' => FALSE,
);
```

In the submission handler, I use the following code.

```
// Get the fid value, upload it and save it to the managed file table. 
$fid = $form_state->getValue(['theimage', 0]);
dpm($fid);
if (!empty($fid)) {
  $file = File::load($fid);
  $file->setPermanent();
  $file->save(); 
}
```

Any thoughts, solutions, or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i havent worked with drupal for almost a year and i dont have exact piece of code for reference at hand but if i rememebr correctly the the file field output can be three different types: fileid, [0=>fileid] or [fids => [0 => fileid]] or something like that. So debug the field directly, not the 0 sub-value and you'll what yo uare getting...or better yet the thole form state values array.

Comment: As @IvanJaros said first debug the field either using `dpm($form_state->getValues())` or `dpm($form_state->getValue(['theimage']))`. Then you may get how the structure of managed file is being rendered with FID.

Comment: Thanks @IvanJaros .Your suggestion definitely put me on the right path.

Comment: Thanks @AjayReddy. Your suggestion definitely put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of digging/debugging i discovered that i could not pull any data from the "manage_file" field while using the PrivateTempStore in my Multi-Step form. After disabling the form cache, i began to get the values and the expected behavior by using:

```
$form_state->disableCache();
```

My Submit Handler

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
 /**
 *  Fixes image upload bug in form. Does not work unless we 
 disable the cache while using PrivateTempStore
 **/

 $form_state->disableCache();

.......

}
```

See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2647812#comment-11683961

Comment: A word of warning here: disabling the cache like this also disables adding elements dynamically such as paragraph types or fields with multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

$form_state will show NULL or empty arrays in the file upload if you don't use the proper upload function. The file hasn't been uploaded yet.

In the validation function, for example, you should use the function file_save_upload.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);

  $file = file_save_upload('banner_image', array(), FALSE, 0, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
}
```